# How To Write The equation for a line given a set of co-ordinates

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, plane-curves

I'm trying to learn how can I write the equation for a line given all the points that belongs in the line.

I'm looking to find the equation for a curve.

An example set of points is:

$$\{ (24,11), (25,11), (25,12), (25,13), (25,14), (25,15), (24,16), (23,15), (23,14), (23,13), (24,12) \}$$

Thanks in advance for the help :)

EDIT:

SORRY, $$\{ (24,11), (25,11), (25,12), (25,13), (25,14), (25,15), (24,16), (23,15), (23,14), (23,13), (24,12) \}$$

I accidentally interchanged the $X,Y$ values :(

This is the new co-ordinates

$$\{ (11,24), (11,25), (12,25), (13,25), (14,25), (15,25), (16,24), (15,23), (14,23), (13,23), (12,24) \}$$

Comment: Do you mean a line of best fit? Or would you like an interpolating polynomial?

Comment: The points you listed do not belong to a straight line.

Comment: are you looking for [spline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)) or just trying to guess the original equation for the curve?

Comment: @nbubis I'm looking to make a equation for a curve

Comment: @V-X not exactly a spline as it won't be smooth and also it will have at least a minimum of 60-80 co-ordinate points

Comment: @sreejith You do realize that you can't fit a curve through $(11,24)$ and $(11,25)$ right?

Comment: Yes, I do, the co-ordinates I gave is the part of a bigger set straight lines are used to join curve points that's why it happened :(

Answer (score 2):

From the picture we see that your coordinates create the picture: 
[image]

and do not define a line. For all of your coordinates to define a line, there would have to be pairwise uniform $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ between any $(x_i,y_i)$ and $(x_j,y_j)$ in your list, with $i\ne j$.

Here what is meant by  $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ is: $\dfrac{y_j-y_i}{x_j-x_i}$

For example: $\{(3,6),(2,5),(4,7),(5,8)\}$ define the line: $y=x+3$. Why? 
The points are *colinear* because for any two points, you'll observe the same ratio of *rise* to *run*. 
For example, the ratio of rise to run between the second coordinate and the third coordinate is: 
$$
\dfrac{y_3-y_2}{x_3-x_2}= \dfrac{7-5}{4-2} =\dfrac{2}{2} = 1
$$
Testing any other two points would yield the same result. 
The ratio of *rise* to *run* is often called the *slope* of the line and is denoted by *m*
Since we have this uniform *slope* between any two points, we know for a particular point, $(x_0,y_0)$:
$$
m = \frac{y-y_0}{x-x_0}
$$
Where $x$ and $y$ are subject to choice. 
Using this result, the equation of the line is thus:
$$
y-y_0=m(x-x_0)
$$
So in our example, let $(x_0,y_0) = (2,5)$
Then,
$$
y-5=1(x-2) 
$$
and Voila! 
$$
y=x-3
$$

Other interpretations of your question such as a "line of best fit" or an interpolating polynomial would merit a different answer altogether.

The line of best fit is given by:
$$
y = -0.125806x + 25.851613
$$
using your new coordinates.

The slope coefficient and $y$-intercept are given by:
$$
m = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iy_i - n\bar{x}\bar{y}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2-n\bar{x}^{2}}\\
b= \bar{y} - m\bar{x}
$$
Where
$$
 \bar{x}: \text{mean of}\;\; x\\
   \bar{y}: \text{mean of}\;\; y\\
   x_i: \text{the $i^{th}$ number of}\;\;x\\
   y_i: \text{the $i^{th}$ number of}\;\; y\\
   n:\text{total numbers of}\;\; x \;\;\text{or}\;\; y
$$

Comment: @Rustin I'm looking for finding equation for a curve

Comment: @Rustin can I use slope equation to find equation for a curve?

Comment: @sreejith There can be no curve that goes through those points. The simple fact is that you have one $x$ value corresponding to more than one $y$ value.